# Redirecting dbaccess output loses a character

Tags: bash, shell, informix

I have a very weird problem when using a dump from informix database via the dbaccess executable.

Here is how the problem behaves:

```
~ # echo "unload to /dev/stdout [ select statement ]" |  dbaccess db 2>/dev/null
H300|1|

~ # echo "unload to /dev/stdout [ select statement ]" |  dbaccess db 2>/dev/null  | hexdump -C
00000000  48 33 30 30 7c 31 7c 0a  0a                       |H300|1|..|
00000009
~ # echo "unload to /dev/stdout [ select statement ]" |  dbaccess db 2>/dev/null > redir
~ # cat redir

300|1|
~ # hexdump -C redir
00000000  0a 33 30 30 7c 31 7c 0a                           |.300|1|.|
00000008
~ #
```

The correct output is "H300|1|" but when I redirect that I get something weird. What I am suspecting is that dbacess executable writes something to stdout that interferes with the dump that is also written to the same file (/dev/stdout).

Unloading to a different file than stdout yields this output:

```
~ # cat not_stdout
H300|1|
~ # hexdump -C not_stdout
00000000  48 33 30 30 7c 31 7c 0a                           |H300|1|.|
00000008
~ #
```

NOTE: If I gzip -c the output the gzipped file contains valid data, with no missing characters, just like the input.

Database setup:

```
~ # echo "SELECT DBINFO('version', 'full') FROM "informix".systables WHERE tabid = 1" | dbaccess sysuser

Database selected.



(constant)

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC9W3

1 row(s) retrieved.



Database closed.

~ # dbaccess -version
Program Name:   dbaccess
Build Version:  11.50.FC9W3
Build Number:   N014
Build Host:     vidar
Build OS:       Linux 2.6.9-34.ELsmp
Build Date:     Fri Mar 29 08:40:42 CDT 2013
GLS Version:    glslib-4.50.FC12
~ # dbaccess -V
DB-Access Version 11.50.FC9W3 Software Serial Number AAA#B000000
~ #
```

Running on this OSes with the same behavior:

```
test_shell:cat /etc/SUSE-brand
SLE
VERSION = 15
test_shell:uname -a
Linux test-linux 5.3.18-22-default #1 SMP Wed Jun 3 12:16:43 UTC 2020 (720aeba) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
test_shell:



test_shell2:/home/# cat /etc/SuSE-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 4
test_shell2:/home/# uname -a
Linux test-linux 3.0.101-63-default #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 16:02:31 UTC 2015 (4b89d0c) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
test_shell2:/home/# cat /etc/SuSE-brand
SLES
VERSION = 11
CO-BRANDS = SLE openSUSE
test_shell2:/home/#
```

So this happens on both SLES15SP2 and SLES11SP4. I can do my work by simply using the cat/tee hacks or gzip -c, but I just want an explanation, if possible.

Comment: Your hypothesis seems off. If the database wrote something more, you would see the regular output *and* whatever else it wrote.

Comment: What about `echo .... | dbaccess | cat > file`? Or `dbaccess | tee file`? Does it change the output? `Unloading to a different file ` could be, `/dev/stdout` is not seekable, and that would be the reason? Could you try with a pipe? Somethink like `mkpipe /tmp/temppipe` then open `hexdump -C /tmp/temppipe` in one terminal and do the `unload /tmp/temppipe` in another?

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to avoid a pipe now since current script blocks in case of error. This solution would be best, I just want to understand why this happens when I don't use gzip. With tee/cat it works fine.

Comment: @tripleee I just to understand this behavior as it is pretty weird. As mentioned above if I add tee/cat to the pipeline it works fine

Comment: Which version of Informix (DB-Access) on which platform (o/s and version)?  (If you run `dbaccess -version`, it should give all the information and more; running `dbaccess -V` will print the short version of the information.  If you run `SELECT DBINFO('version', 'full') FROM "informix".systables WHERE tabid = 1` should tell you about the server version; that might be different from the DB-Access version.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've updated my answer to contain that information. Please see above.

Comment: Thanks for the version information.  Are you running it on a Linux 2.6 kernel, or something later.  I'm puzzled; the RHEL 7 Linux box I tried your code on refuses to recognize `/dev/stdout` in a pipeline, and I think it is likely the machine at fault.  It recognizes it without a pipe line.  It probably needs a reboot (but I have to negotiate with colleagues to do that).  I'll probably try a different machine first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've updated the question with the OS and Kernel version I'm using. It's about SLES distro (11SP4 - old one) and 15SP2 (the new one we are porting the application to).

Comment: I've made a slight mistake for the old platform but now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in my case was to use grep like this (I will explain the `|| true` reason right away.

```
echo "unload to /dev/stdout delimiter '|' [ select statement ]" |  dbaccess db 2>/dev/null | (grep '|' || true)
```

I did a grep to have only the lines containing some data (as long as the '|' is used as delimiter.

I used `|| true` to make sure none of the commands from the pipeline fails as I verify them with `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` in bash.

I will not choose this as the proper answer unless someone else offers an explanation for this in a reasonable amount of time.

As mentioned, I already fixed the issue and documented everything.

Comment: but.. you said `With tee/cat it works fine` so just `| cat`

Comment: @KamilCuk I need to filter the lines with information as dbaccess also makes some empty line output.